# Fetch how many failure and success did each person (name) have

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `buggy`, the dummy dataset link can be see here
https://github.com/FirzaCank/Project/blob/main/SQL/IFG%20test/Dataset%20Dummy%20no%205.sql

Which contains:

1. id (INT)
2. name (VARCHAR)
3. bug (INT, contains the numbers 0 and 1)

With dataset explanations on 'bug' column are:

- 0, it means fault / failure
- 1, it means success
- If there is no 'fault', then the 'fault' value will be filled with '0' (null is okay too), so is 'success'

I've tried a MySQL query like this:

```
SELECT name,
    CASE
    WHEN bug = 0 THEN COUNT(bug)
    END AS failure,
    CASE
    WHEN bug = 1 THEN COUNT(bug)
    END AS success
FROM buggy
GROUP BY name;
```

The desire output is like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhfiC.jpg), but as far as I've tried in the above syntax it just came out like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fPyV.jpg)

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `SUM` instead of `Count`.

```
SELECT 
name, 
SUM(IF(bug = 0, 1, 0)) as fault,
SUM(IF(bug = 1, 1, 0)) as success
FROM buggy
GROUP BY name
```

This counts the number of rows satisfying the conditions inside the `IF` function.

Answer (score 1):

this sql will give wanted result

```
SELECT t.name , SUM(t.failure) as failure , SUM(t.success) as success

from ( SELECT name ,  CASE
WHEN bug < 1 THEN COUNT(bug) ELSE 0  
END AS failure,
CASE
WHEN bug = 1 THEN COUNT(bug) ELSE 0  
END AS success
FROM buggy
GROUP BY name,bug ) t

GROUP BY t.name;
```